# Ruby on Rails uncapitalize first letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lowercase, capitalize

I'm running Rails 2.3.2.

How do I convert `"Cool"` to `"cool"`? I know `"Cool".downcase` works, but is there a Ruby/Rails method that does the opposite of `capitalize`, i.e., `uncapitalize` or `decapitalize`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is no inverse of `capitalize`, but you can feel free to roll your own:

```
class String
  def uncapitalize 
    self[0, 1].downcase + self[1..-1]
  end
end
```

Comment: Where should we add this method?

Comment: @Vadorequest The method? Add it on the String class, as shown in the answer.

Comment: In a standard Rails app, it would probably make sense to add it to a new file in `/config/initializers`

Comment: @Ajedi32 Well, it maybe looks obvious to you, but not to me. Thanks Dave.

Answer (score 121):

There is also:

```
"coolat_cat".camelize(:lower) # => "coolCat"
```

Comment: This does require ActiveRecord tho : http://apidock.com/rails/String/camelize (After reading the question, it does state it is already with Rails)

Comment: @Ian Vaughan: ActiveSupport to be more precise

Comment: They updated the method signature around v4.2.7. It now takes a boolean, like `camelize(uppercase_first_letter = true)` http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/String/camelize

Comment: @animatedgif there's two methods, [Inflector.#camelize(term, uppercase_first_letter)](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/4.2.7.1/ActiveSupport/Inflector#camelize-instance_method) which takes a string to camelize and a boolean, [String#camelize(first_letter)](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/4.2.7.1/String#camelize-instance_method) which camelizes `self` and takes a symbol `:upper` or `:lower`. I think the apidock docs are in error.

Comment: Definitely a rails thing but damn its nice to have!

Answer (score 11):

You could also do this with a simple `sub`:

```
"Cool".sub(/^[A-Z]/) {|f| f.downcase }
```

Comment: note that `"Cool".sub(/^[A-Z]/, &:downcase)` is enough

Comment: `"CoolTrick".sub(/^[[:alpha:]]/) {|f| f.downcase }`

Answer (score 9):

```
str = "Directly to the south"
str[0] = str[0].downcase
puts str
#=> "directly to the south"
```

Comment: This not only the most readable method, but also and by far the most performant one, even if you protect it by some kind of ternary operator or if statement to ensure that str is not nil. This should be the accepted answer. Thanks @boulder_ruby

Answer (score 5):

There is no real inverse of capitalize, but I think `underscore` comes close.

```
"CoolCat".underscore  #=> "cool_cat"
"cool_cat".capitalize #=> "Cool_cat"
"cool_cat".camelize   #=> "CoolCat"
```

**Edit:** `underscore` is of course the inverse of `camelize`, not `capitalize`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use tap (so that it fits on one line):

```
"JonSkeet".tap { |e| e[0] = e[0].downcase } # => "jonSkeet"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an inverse of `capitalize` called `swapcase`:

```
"Cool Cat".swapcase   #=> "cOOL cAT"
```

Answer (score 2):

### String#downcase_first (Rails 7.1+)

Starting from `Rails 7.1`, there is a [String#downcase_first](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-downcase_first) method:

> Converts the first character to lowercase.

For example:

```rb
'If they enjoyed The Matrix'.downcase_first # => "if they enjoyed The Matrix"
'I'.downcase_first                          # => "i"
''.downcase_first                           # => ""
```

**Sources:**

- [String#downcase_first](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-downcase_first).
- [ActiveSupport::Inflector#downcase_first](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-downcase_first).
- [Add String#downcase_first method](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45827).

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ruby Facets, you can lowercase the first letter:

https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/string/uppercase.rb

Answer (score 1):

```
name = "Viru"

name = name.slice(0).downcase + name[1..(name.length)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
'Cool'.sub(/^([A-Z])/) { $1.tr!('[A-Z]', '[a-z]') }
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/XSD/CodeGen/GenSupport/uncapitalize