# Forcing "humanized" names of fields to be lowercase in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, humanize

As far as I know, the accepted way to set the "humanized" names of fields in Rails 3 is to use locales:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      member:
        username: 'username' # rather than 'Username'
```

However, I simply want Rails 3 to use lowercase versions of its default humanized names. Is there an easy, built-in way to do this?

An example to help clarify: When inside of a `form_for`, `<%= f.label :username %>` displays "Username" by default. I want it to display "username".

Comment: By "humanized" do you mean "localized"? Or actually the humanize form via a method like http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize

Comment: @raidfive Thank you for the opportunity to clarify. I've updated the question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474028/ruby-on-rails-uncapitalize-first-letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `label` helper defaults to using [human_attribute_name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Translation.html#method-i-human_attribute_name) to turn an attribute into a human name.  If you look at the source, `human_attribute_name` tries a few things before falling back to `attributes.to_s.humanize`.  It tries the translation first, and then it looks for a `:default` option in the options hash.

So, the simplest/best way to get the functionality you want is to override `human_attribute_name` with your own that provides a `:default` option and then calls the original.  Rails provides a reasonable way to do this sort of thing with `alias_method_chain`, so...

#### I've heard enough, just give me the answer!

Put the following in any file in `config/initializers` and restart your app:

```
module ActiveModel
  module Translation
    def human_attribute_name_with_foo attribute, options = {}
      human_attribute_name_without_foo attribute, options.merge( :default => attribute.humanize.downcase )
    end

    alias_method_chain :human_attribute_name, :foo
  end
end
```

Comment: Epic! I had been using locales all along. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
I solved it via css:

In foo.html.erb:

```
<%= f.label :username, :class => "my_class" %>
```

In bar.css:

```
label.my_class {
    text-transform:   lowercase;
}
```

I would prefer a different solution, too. But that's the only one I've been able to find, so far.

Comment: I've voted you up for bringing this question back to life, and for providing a solution that does result in lowercase letters being displayed. I've decided to go with the other answer, though.

Comment: I'd argue that CSS is the wrong place to do this. This is a server issue so fix it on the server.